# Tengo un ejecutable hecho en Python con interfaz grafica Tkinter, quiero ponerlo a funcionar en otro PC ¿Cómo Hago?

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite, pyinstaller, exe

Utilizo algunas librerías externas como: reportlab, imutils ,numpy y algunas imagenes para los logos y botones, el ejecutable hace que el usuario llene un formulario y con este se fabrique un PDF en una ubicación especifica, luego se envia un correo con el pdf adjunto, trabaja tambien con conexion a dos bases de datos hechas con sqlite para almacenar los registros, soy nuevo en programacion pero me gustaria aprender a usar mi aplicacion en otro pc, hacer el ejecutable ya lo tengo claro y lo hago con auto-py-to-exe, muchas gracias

Comment: buenas tardas, me sumo a esta duda antigua, desarrollé una app con tkinter la compilo en un exe, funciona correcto, pero al compartir el dist, no logro funcione en otra pc. Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español!
Lo que necesitas es re-compilar tu código en cada uno de los sistemas operativos para los que quieras usarlo. Me explico:
¿Quieres compilarlo para Linux? Compilalo en una PC con Linux o en una máquina virtual con Linux. Recuerda que debes instalar los módulos usados con pip, y además usar nuitka en el caso de Linux.